# Show that If $T$ and $S$ are Isometric Transformations, so is $TS$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know that - $T$ is Isometic $ \iff\left\| Tv \right\| = \left\| v \right\|$

So my proof is as such:
$\left\| TS(v) \right\| = \left\| T\circ S(v) \right\| = \left\| T(S(v)) \right\| = \left\| S(v) \right\| = \left\| v \right\|$

With the last two steps using the iff statement above.

Is my proof correct? can I use that iff statement for that proof?

(Hopefully I translated the words well, I dont study Algebra in English)

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: By the transitive property of equality, this is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

$\left\| TS(v) \right\| = \left\| T\circ S(v) \right\| = \left\| T(S(v)) \right\| = \left\| S(v) \right\| = \left\| v \right\|$